# Toolbar and TableView is giving me headaches

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm having trouble implementing a toolbar (below my navigationbar) and a tableview. In my storyboard I created a normal `ViewController`, then made it part of the `NavigationController`, then added a `UIToolBar` and a `UITableView`. After this was done, I created the `ViewController` files. It all works. However, when I press a button in the toolbar it is being registered as a click on a cell and thus crashing the app. My knowledge isn't sufficient enough for me to be able to fix this, that's why I'm asking here.

Furthermore, if you scroll the toolbar doesn't stay at the top. It scrolls along with the table.

How can I fix these two problems?

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "Ninja.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "AMSlideMenuMainViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+AMSlideMenu.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "NSString+FontAwesome.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *ninjas;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *movies;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *shows;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *profile;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *mainToolBar;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Your watched movies";
    [self addRightMenuButton];

    [self loadNinjas];

    [self.movies setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:24.0],
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.view.tintColor
                                          } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.movies setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-dot-circle-o"]];

    [self.shows setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                           NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:24.0],
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.view.tintColor
                                           } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.shows setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-pencil-square-o"]];

    [self.profile setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:24.0],
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.view.tintColor
                                          } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.profile setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForIconIdentifier:@"fa-plus"]];

    self.mainToolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    self.mainToolBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.ninjas.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.ninjas[indexPath.row] name];

     NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [self.ninjas[indexPath.row] thumbnail]];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"50-50.jpg"]];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 50.0f;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    DetailViewController *detailvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSIndexPath *index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    Ninja *ninja = self.ninjas[index.row];

    detailvc.ninja = ninja;
}


- (void)loadNinjas {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/movies"]];


    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];

    request = [mutableRequest copy];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];

        NSMutableArray *tempNinjas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
            Ninja *ninja = [[Ninja alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
            [tempNinjas addObject:ninja];
        }


        self.ninjas = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempNinjas];
        tempNinjas = nil;

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Shows"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    [operation start];
}


@end
```

And this is the storyboard screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQQAi.jpg

Comment: Can you show a screen capture of your storyboard - particularly the hierarchy of objects in your scene on the left of the starboard editor

Comment: There you go: http://imgur.com/EOe9iQ3

Comment: Your toolbar is a subview of your table, as can be seen from your scene list. It looks like you don't have a main view, other than the table view. Are you sure you used a UIViewController? Did you delete the controller's main view perhaps?

Comment: It's definitely a UITableViewController. I can see the little table lines on the rectangle within the yellow circle on your storyboard. And your toolbar's scrolling because (as @rdelmar may have been implying) it's within your UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have UITableViewController as your view controller, which always has UITableView as its main view and that can't be changed.

What you could do is just drag new UIViewController onto your storyboard, which will come with usual UIView as its main view. Then cut/paste your existing table and toolbar views as your new UIView subviews.

Since toolbar now isn't a subview of your table view, it'll never scroll with it nor will it have any crashes upon taps on its items.

Finally, connect any relevant outlets/actions from the views of your new UIViewController to your new view controller, and don't forget to set the latter as a delegate/data source for your table view (which is done automatically for UITableViewController)